# Can I open a DataSet record by double-clicking a cell in an unbound DataGridView?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, dataset

I have an unbound `DataGridView` that I use to display database search results. The rows are placed programmatically. I have the `DataGridView` object set as Read-Only, but I would like to open the original record in a new Windows `Form` for editing if someone double-clicks one of the cells in a row. I know the event to use to trigger this is `dataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick`, but since dataGridView1 is unbound I am not quite sure what to do next.

Is there a way that I can get the primary key, for instance, from `object sender` or `EventArgs e`? I can get the `RowIndex` from `e`, but that wouldn't be the same as the primary key since (I think) it would reference the row index within the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chris said in the comments below, in order for the SelectedRows property to be populated, you need to set

`dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect`

Otherwise, all you have inside `DataGridViewCellEventArgs e` is the `ColumnIndex` of the column which was double clicked.

Once selection mode has been set, you may be able to do something such as:

```
public void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // sender is just dataGridView1 btw..
    var selectedRow = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    var primaryKey = selectedRow.Cells["primaryKeyColumnName"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... probably the right direction, but the dataRow object has no Table property in this context.

Comment: @armadadrive oops, I think the problem was missing a cast, give the above a try.

Comment: `ArgumentOutOfRange Exception was unhandled.` Thrown by the first line of your suggestion.

Comment: @Tom Studee unbound DataGridView mean there is no .DataBoundItem in this context.

Comment: @armadadrive dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0] suppose there is at least One selected row. From MSDN The SelectionMode property must be set to FullRowSelect or RowHeaderSelect for the SelectedRows property to be populated with selected rows.

Comment: @Chris so a 'cell click' wouldn't count as a FullRowSelect? It seems like it should be relatively easy to find the primary key from a row in the DataGridView programatically. It's there in the row information, I just need it passed to the `DoubleClick` event somehow.

Comment: @Chris in that case if there is no underlying DataRow, there is no defined primary key. He would need to know which cell the primary key was actually in.

Comment: @armadadrive a DataRow's primary key is defined in the DataTable. Without a DataTable, there's no primary key to access. If you know the columnIndex the primaryKey is in, you could use that, but it's obviously not the most elegant solution.

Comment: Perhaps my terminology is incorrect, but the ID that I use as a primary key still exists in each row in the `DataGridView` and will always be unique because it's source IS the primary key.

Comment: @Armadadrive If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, Yes the cellContentDoubleClick or another event can give you the DataGridViewRow index. So you can acess the Row object. If you want to know the "id" (I know from another question that you populate the unbound DGV from DataTable values) you need to know the column index for the "Id" column. Then you access it with something like this row.Cells[index].Value. It helps?

Comment: @Chris @Tom Studee Yeah, the reservation ID is always in the first column. I have laid out the DGV to reflect the column layout of the database. I'll take a stab at this method when I get a chance! Will `dataGridView1.SelectionMode = ...` work in the `DoubleClick` event handler? Is that how I will set up the object to be able to access the DGV Row Index?

Comment: @armadadrive you can do it there, but the best place would be to set it in the designer, or wherever the dgv is instantiated.

Comment: @TomStudee Oh, SelectionMode is a property accessible from the designer? I'm anxious to give this a shot - Chris helped me out a bunch with my previous question and I would like to say thank you to both of you for taking time out of your days to help me once again.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much guys. I set the SelectionMode property to FullRowSelect (exactly what I wanted in the first place) and used the line:
`int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);`
Now I can pass this to a new form and retrieve the record for updating/deleting! Thanks so much for your time. :)

Comment: @armadadrive Glad to hear it :)